# How I fix Problem Interface C# (Console .NET Core):CS0535 and CS1061

Tags: c#, .net-core, interface

I'm a newbie, and have a problem with Interface, I googled but didn't found, I think this error is cause I use **(Console .NET Core)**.

**[EDIT]:** I fixed "SavaData", but I think interface don't work at .Net Core .

The error is that:

**CS0535 'Base' and 'Customer' does not implement interface member 'IPeople.SaveData()'**

> CS0535 C# 'Customer' does not implement interface member
>
> CS1061 C#'Customer' does not contain a definition for and no accessible
>   extension method accepting a first argument of type 'Customer' could
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

and that the problem:

**My Interface**

```
using Customer1;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace Interface
{
    public interface IPeople 
    {
        public void SavaData();
    }
}
```

**My inheritance:**

```
using Interface;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace Base1
{
    public class Base : IPeople
    {
        public string Name;
        public string NPhone; 
        public string CPF;


        public Base(string nome, string Nphone, string CPF)
        {
            //This can't equal a null or blanc
            this.Name = nome;
            this.NPhone = Nphone;
            this.CPF = CPF;
        }
        public Base() { }

        private string DirectoryMaster()
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Directory1"] + this.GetType().Name + ".txt";
        }
        public void SaveData() 
        {

            var SPeople = this.ReadPeople(); 
            SPeople.Add(this);
            if (File.Exists(DirectoryMaster()))
            {
                StreamWriter r = new StreamWriter(DirectoryMaster());
                string Data = "nome;telefone;CPF;"; //n";
                r.WriteLine(Data);
                foreach (Base c in SPeople)
                {
                    var linha = c.Name + ";" + c.NPhone + ";" + c.CPF + ";";
                    r.WriteLine(linha);
                }

                r.Close();
            }
        }

        public virtual List<Base> ReadPeople()
        {
            var dados = new List<Base>();

            if (File.Exists(DirectoryMaster()))
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Your file content is:");
                using (StreamReader arquivo = File.OpenText(DirectoryMaster()))
                {
                    string linha;
                    int i = 0;
                    while ((linha = arquivo.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        i++;
                        if (i == 1) continue;
                        var DataCustomer = linha.Split(';');


                        var b = new Base { Name = DataCustomer[0], NPhone = DataCustomer[1], CPF = DataCustomer[2] };


                        dados.Add(b);

                    }
                }

            }

            return dados;
        }

    }
}
```

**My Customer.cs**

```
using System.Configuration; 
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using User1;



namespace Customer1
{
    public class Customer : IPeople
    {
        public string Name; 
        public string NPhone;
        public string CPF;


        public Customer(string nome, string Nphone, string CPF)
        {

            this.Name = nome;
            this.NPhone = Nphone;
            this.CPF = CPF;
        }
        public Customer()
        {

        }
}
```

Plz help me, tks

Comment: In which line you get this error?

Comment: The error report indicates a problem with `Customer` but you dont show that class.  Also, implementing an interface is not inheritance; and those public members (`Name` etc) ought to be private and probably be properties.  And there are thousands of Google hits for CS0535; any new answers are not likely to be any different than those because it is the same problem.

Comment: You can not assign access modifiers inside of an interface so you should get an error about the `public` before `SaveData`

Comment: The error is that : CS0535 'Base' does not implement interface member 'IPeople.SavaData()'

Comment: Add `Customer` Class, please.

Comment: As the first thing, remove `public` from your Interface, then correct the **typo** and change `Sava` to `Save`

Comment: When a class Implements an Interface, It must implement all members of this Interface. It means that in your `Base` and `Customer` you have to have a `public void SaveData()` method. this error said that you have not implemented this method.

Comment: @HamedMoghadasi I fix the Typo 'SAVA' to 'Save' , I tried remove 'public' from Interface, but still same error, CS0535 'Customer' does not implement interface member 'IPeople.SaveData()'

Comment: @Rodrigo now Implemente `SaveData()` in `Base` and `Customer` class.

Comment: After your revision: `Customer` doesn't implement `SaveData` exactly as the exception message tells you. You probably want to inherit `Customer` from `Base`.

Answer (score 2):

One of the issues you're seeing is related to a typo in your interface.

```
public void SavaData();
```

The above code should instead be:

```
void SaveData();
```

Comment: Did you mean it should be `void SaveData();` without the `public`?  Also that's a CS0106 which is not one that the OP listed, but is indeed an issue with the code they posted.

Comment: I tried that , but dont  work

Comment: Please can you post the customer class and update your question with the current compiler errors if they have changed?

Comment: Error: CS0535 'Base' and 'Customer' does not implement interface member 'IPeople.SavaData()'

Comment: It strangely looks like it hasn't been updated based on the typo still being there, have you saved the file?

Answer (score 0):

So, the first error that you have is saying that you are implementing an interface in Customer class, but you are not implementing the methods from that interface. That's why that issue is happening.

One more thing, the interface, doesnt need the public on it`s definition of the method.

The second error, probably you are trying to pass a Customer on a constructor of some class, but you didn't add the "using Customer" on that class in specific. So .NET could`t find the class that you want.

Please, try to put the Customer class for us, because, it will be easier to see if that's really the error.